# Understanding HardRouteConstraint

Tags: reference-request, vehicle-routing, java

I am trying to understand the route constraints in jsprit. While I got the concept of HardActivityConstraint, I am unable to have clarity on HardRouteConstraint.

Can someone, preferably with a simple example explain to me how it works, what is its relevance with JobInsertionContext, how sending true/false impacts the routes? Or direct me to any literature or blog where I can read and understand.

Comment: Do you have the force to use Jsprit or are you interested to develop a MIP formulation?

Comment: I have a use case so I am using jsprit for that. As far as MIP is concerned, I am currently studying it.

Comment: There are many papers which the authors using MIP to introduce routing constraints. I hope [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0305054814001671) paper would be interest.